# User is not authorized to read view FreeTextInvoiceHeaderEntity. Request denied

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7

I've created this custom role for my user see he can see only the FreeTextInvoice

[image]

When he loged in, he see the below:

[image]

And the below screen as read only:

[image]

I'm trying to see the `https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com/data/FreeTextInvoiceHeaders` but gettong `User is not authorized to read view FreeTextInvoiceHeaderEntity. Request denied.`

[image]

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments recieved, i tried checking the entity permissions, and ended up with this screen, no idea how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Check the cross references of the entity. Entities usually have their own privileges, they are maybe missing in the custom security role?

Comment: @FH-Inway how can I do this check, or how can I create a role with a read/write privileges for specific entity?

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/application-explorer. It is the "Find references" action.

Comment: Thanks @FH-Inway I could not find privilages, and attached screenshoot as an update to my question above, approciate to have alook and guide me furthure.

Comment: Could you create a new question for this? Comments are not a good fit to provide guidance on this.